# Liberator 3 for fits format

Tags: data-analysis

How to set in Liberator 3 the reverse color scale? I would like to have stars black and the surroundings white. Or could you recommend me another program that has this ability?

[image]

Comment: I do not know how to use Liberator, but ... you can try using openCV for that, load an image in bw (or something like that), and then make all black pixels white and vice versa ... you would have to write some code but it should be rather short.

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing that in FITS Liberator; it's not really designed to be an image-*viewing* program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you check out [SAOimage DS9](http://ds9.si.edu/site/Home.html), which is one of the most commonly used FITS viewers (probably *the* most commonly used one) among professional astronomers. It allows you to display images with a variety of different scalings and color maps (and, yes, there is an "Invert Colormap" setting under the "Color" menu).

Comment: Thank you very much